# Where to put jboss-web.xml for ejb-jar?

Tags: wildfly, undertow, jbossws

We have the following situation:

- We have a SOAP WebService that is implemented using JBossWS. It is an EJB inside an EJB JAR inside an EAR.
- We have set up a second dedicated server with a dedicated port inside the undertow subsystem of Wildfly.
- We want to deploy the SOAP WebService only on the dedicated server/port not the default server of the undertow subsystem. For normal WAR deployments we could achieve this using `<server-instance>` in `WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml` . We have not found a way to make this work for an EJB JAR inside and EAR. This this possible? If so where does `jboss-web.xml` need to be placed?

Comment: A JAR is not a web archive so the `jboss-web.xml` wouldn't work. You'd have to make it a WAR for that to work.

Comment: You should be able to reach `jboss` configuration on top `EJB` and configure a reverse proxy there to the undertow `EJB` (a sample configuration can be found here https://developer.jboss.org/thread/109970).. What am I missing?

Comment: @ymz when I say server I mean <server> inside the undertow subsystem, we have different deployments inside the same Wildfly instance which require a different HTTP listener configuration.

Answer (score 1):

`jboss-ejb3.xml` is a custom deployment descriptor we can use this either in `ejb-jar` or `war` archives. If in `ejb-jar` then it must inside `META-INF` folder or if `web` then in   `WEB-INF` folder. Follow  [this link](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/jboss-ejb3.xml+Reference?_sscc=t) for more information.

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no way to specify an undertow server instance inside `jboss-ejb3.xml`.